# how to Group the data in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I am using below code :  to get the data based on months and AccountName.

```
SELECT
CONVERT(Date,JD.CreatedDateTime) as Dated,
 DATENAME(Month,JD.CreatedDateTime) as [Month],
A.AccountName as [Account_Name],

Sum(JD.credit + JD.Debit) as Amount
FROM AccountGroup AG
INNER JOIN AccountType AT ON AG.AccountGroupID=AT.AccountGroupID
Right join Account A on A.AccountTypeID = AT.AccountTypeID 
Inner join JournalMasterDetail JD on JD.AccountID = A.AccountID
where AG.AccountGroupID =4  and JD.CreatedDateTime >=DATEADD(month,-12,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0))

group by 
A.AccountName,
JD.CreatedDateTime
```

But subgroup of AccountName is not working...

I got  this result :

[image]

Desired result is :

```
Dated        Month      Account_Name         Amount
2014-03-01   February   Sales                910.00
2014-03-01   February   Services             350.00

2014-03-06   March      Sales                 69:99
2014-03-06   March      Cash Discount Given   44.99
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are grouping by a datetime field but only displaying the date part. The entries may be for the same date but different times. For group by these are distinct values. You either need to group by date:

```
group by A.AccountName, CONVERT(Date,JD.CreatedDateTime)
```

or prepare the query in a CTE for example and then group:

```
with cte as
(
  SELECT CONVERT(Date,JD.CreatedDateTime) as Dated, ...
)
select Dated, ... from cte group by Dated, ...
```